# How to update Model attributes in production

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django app which I deployed three years ago that has been working perfectly and making our life in the laboratory easier. Recently there was a need that wasn't contemplated in the beginning, and I have added some functionality to the app.
This involved modifying some Model methods and some AdminModel methods as well.
Unfortunately web development is not my field and this was a single thing that I did with Python in my spare time and now I'm not sure what will happen If I pull the changes from the repository. I remember that in development I had to use

```
manage.py migrate
manage.py makemigrations
```

after any changes to the models attributes. In this case it's only methods that I have modified. Do I still need to run these commands in the production server? Will I loose data (this can not be tolerated)? I'm using the sqlite standard database that django generates by default.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

New or changed Model methods don't need migrations. Migrations get generated only when you add, remove, or modify model *fields*. In other words, you change the structure of the underlying DB table.

Simple migrations aren't anything to be scared about. If you add a new field with a default, all existing objects will get the new field added with the default value.

First

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

to check for errors and to create the migrations file (in your_model/migrations/) then

```
./manage.py migrate
```

to apply them.

Obviously you should do this on a test database first before you change your production data. It's also a good idea to back up your production database before migrating, just in case. (I've never yet needed the backup but I like knowing it exists! )

Comment: That's what I guessed. I will pull the changes from the repo and hope for the best then! I will later need to add fields to some models, I hope I don't screw anything up. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, actually I also updated methods of ModelAdmin and now those methods doesnt appear on the admin page :/ I think I have to run makemigrations for them to appear but it's throwing me error about missing files